# Why doesn't this Mac full screen code work?

Tags: macos, fullscreen

This did not work for me.
Stack flow wanted more details.
The details are , this is the code and it did not work.
I am trying to figure out why.

```
- (IBAction)ButtonPush:(id)sender {


NSWindowCollectionBehavior behavior = [self.window collectionBehavior];
behavior |= NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenPrimary;
[self.window setCollectionBehavior:behavior];

}
```

Comment: What does "did not work" mean? Did you get an error message? Did demons fly out of your nose?

Comment: @Wooble Does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this, but from 5 minutes of reading the Apple docs I reckon:

The code you provide needs to be done only once, perhaps when the view is added to the window:

```
- (void)viewDidMoveToWindow {
    if ([self window]) {
        NSWindowCollectionBehavior behavior = [[self window] collectionBehavior];
        behavior |= NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenPrimary;
        [[self window] setCollectionBehavior:behavior];
    }
}
```

And having set the windows behaviour, you should be able to toggle full-screen using [`[NSWindow toggleFullscreen]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/toggleFullScreen%3a):

```
- (IBAction)toggleFullscreen:(id)sender {
    [[self window] toggleFullscreen];
}
```

Comment: Trying to get it to work with a button action. Is that not possible? This button event is in appDelegate file. Is that the wrong place?

Comment: My answer includes an action selector for just that purpose.

Comment: Got button event but didn't understand "when the view is added to the window". Is that a place , time, both , or neither? If its a place I don't know where it is.

Comment: As shown, you put the code in the overridden `viewDidMoveToWindow` method.